# What can a hacker do with a card number without CVV?

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card

From my experience a card can not be used for online payment without a valid CVV, then why is it still always emphasized that card number must be protected?
What can a hacker do, assume that he has all the information on the front side of the card (card number, holder name, expiry date) but not the CVV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only fields required to charge a credit card are the number (also called a PAN or personal account number), the expiration date, and an amount. Without the CVV it is still very possible to charge the card.

Many merchants will require the CVV and/or postal code as basic anti-fraud mechanisms. There is also an incentive for many merchants as providing these can qualify them for lower interchange rates, the service fee paid by merchants to the card network.